# What is the graded ring of $(S^n)^{\times m}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

The cohomology algebra of $X=(S^2)^{\times n}$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$ is $H^*(X) = \mathbb{Z}[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]/(x_1^2,\dotsc,x_n^2)$.

My question is that what is  the cohomology algebra of $(S^m)^{\times n}$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$? Or at least when $m$'s are even.

Comment: In general the cohomology ring of $S^m$ is $\mathbb Z[x]/x^2$, where $x$ has degree $m$. So by Kunneth the cohomology ring of $(S^m)^{\times n}$ is $H^*(X)=\mathbb Z[x_1,\dots,x_n]/(x_1^2,\dots,x_n^2)$ where the elements $x_i$ have degree $m$.

Comment: And if $m$ is odd, it's an exterior algebra.

Comment: @KentaS Thanks you very much. I got it. Could you please give a reference about it?

Comment: This is example 3.16 of Hatcher's book.

Comment: @KentaS Thanks very much. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri Thank you so much for your comment. You've got a point there.